# Zero visibility while editing a message in a chat room

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow

I was having a conversation on one of the questions with a member of `stackoverflow.com` and I came across to edit my message and after clicking on edit I was presented with this.

[image]

You can see that the text inside the message box isn't visible at all and it's really hard to edit a message.

It would be good if we can update the section to change the font color or the bg-color at least when the edit button is clicked.

## `EDIT`

I was using `Chrome Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit)` at the time I was having the chat, and I don't have any themes installed in the browser.

Comment: Do you have a private theme script (white on black) installed?

Comment: nope i never did @πάνταῥεῖ you are talking about browser themes arent you?

Comment: Is that a screenshot image, or how did you manage the white on black?

Comment: yes, that is a screenshot image and the message turns to that color (white font on gray bg) as soon you click edit, doesn't it behave the same way for you when you click to edit any sent message? @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: just did it again see here https://imgur.com/a/lakswNc @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @Aurora0001 isnt `private-messaging` tag relevant to it?

Comment: From the green dot in the chatbox corner I am guessing you are using grammarly extension. Try disabling it.. it should work. Had the same issue. I had to disable it in chat SE sites

Comment: i love you @SurajRao :D that is it , you can post it as an answer and i will mark as correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not an issue with Stackexchange Chat per se but a compatibility problem with the Grammarly Extension.

Click on the Grammarly icon in the browser and deselect the option

```
Check Grammar and Spelling on Chat.<StackexchangeSite>.com
```

You could submit a report to Grammarly extension to fix this issue.